# How do you create the database using code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, sql-server-express

I am trying to learn Entity Framework.

I'd like to follow a code first example.

I've read over everything on the following link, but I feel like they skipped over some steps.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx

I googled how to make a user for sql-express. I created one called "EFLearn" with password "EFLearn" I did the same with how to create the database and I created on called "EFLearnDB":

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I looked up what a connection string for Sql Express looks like and put it in my app config.

I created my solution and some classes to represent my data, along with my context as follows:

```
namespace EFLearning {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            using (var manufacturingDbContext = new ManufacturingDbContext()) {
                var good = new Good() { Name = "Water" };

                manufacturingDbContext.Goods.Add(good);
                manufacturingDbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace Domain {

    public class ManufacturingDbContext :DbContext {

        public DbSet<Good> Goods { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }

        public ManufacturingDbContext() : base("name=EFLearnConnectionString") {

        }
    }
}

namespace Domain
{
    public class Good
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double BaseValue { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Domain {
    public class Manufacturer {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public ICollection<ManufacturingCapability> ManufacturingCapabilities { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Domain {
    public class ManufacturingCapability {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ManufacturingInput> Inputs { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ManufacturingOutput> Outputs { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan CycleTime { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Domain {
    public class ManufacturingInput {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Good Good { get; set; }
        public uint Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Domain {
    public class ManufacturingOutput {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Good Good { get; set; }
        public uint Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've got the following AppConfig:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFLearnConnectionString"
    connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=EFLearnDb;User Id=EFLearn;Password=EFLearn;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I run the program and I expect tables to be created. However, instead, I get the following exception:

```
+       $exception  {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
```

What am I missing?

Comment: *I believe I created one called "EFLearnDB"* -- We can't really do much about things you're not sure of. So did or didn't you? Use SQL Server Management Studio to figure it out. Also check if `Server=localhost` is correct. I'd expect an instance name there, like `Server=(local)\sqlexpress`.

Comment: @Gert Sure. It is there. I used Sql Management Studio to create it. Added screenshot to OP. Intestingly, I cannot connect to it in Visual Studio either, through the server explorer, using MS SQL Server for data source choice and .NET Data Provider for SQL Server. When it looks for servers, it comes up blank.

Comment: If I change the connection string to use (local)\scqlexpress as you described, the exception changes to a login failed exception, rather than a cannot connect. Progress. I will add a screenshot of the user I made's properties.

Comment: Your password in app.config is spelled "EfLearn", but in your wording at the top of the post, it has it as "EFLearn" (the capital F).

Comment: @user Yea, I caught that and tried with a capital. Still get failed login.

Comment: Are you sure that EFLearn user has proper permissions for the database?

Comment: @user just added screenshots of all the properties. I haven't setup a user in ages, so I am sure I am doing it wrong.

Comment: That should be enough to connect....user account wont be able to select/insert/update as is, but should still connect.   Have you tried connecting via SSMS with the instance name specified and the user account?

Comment: @user yes, If I try to connect via SSMS I get the same error. Login Failed.

Comment: Since assuming your domain account works (and what you are using to configure), does the server allow for mixed mode authentication?

Comment: @user I am not sure what mixed mode is or where to look. I can connect and configure using windows auth with my domain account, but it fails with sql server auth using the EFLearn account.

Comment: You have to enable mixed mode authentication to allow a non-windows domain account to connect.  You specify this at the server level.   Right click on server and select Properties.   Select the "Security" page.   At the top you should see "Server authentication" section.   Select "SQL Server and Windows Auth mode" option.

Comment: Ok, after I did that, I don't get the login exception anymore. I can also log into SSMS with the EFLearn login now. I can connect in Visual Studio as well. The program runs to completion and I see the tables. Thanks! If you want to leave that as an answer I can mark it answered.

Comment: Cool....glad you got it working.   Will post answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things need to happen to get connectivity working:

1)  Instance name of SQLEXPRESS needs to be set in the connection string.

2)  Mixed mode authentication needs to be enabled on the server to allow for non-Windows domain accounts to connnect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to connect to the instance via SQL Server Management Studio with the EFLearn user and tell us whether it can connect to the instance. If not, please tell us the error message.

Could you please try to change the Server name to hostname\instancename(CPISZ1-LT\SQLEXPRESS) in the connection string.